# Angular display title of selected component

Tags: angular, typescript, components, title

My question is quite simple.

[image: My structure]

In the `router-outlet` I display my pages for example `/contact`, `/home` or `/meetus`

(How) can I display the name of the active component in the `{{title}}`?

Is this even possible or do I have to move my title bar inside every component?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a an [AppService](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-title?embed=1&file=src/app/app.service.ts) which holds the application `title` and provides it as an observable (with accessor method such as `get` and `set`).

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private title = new BehaviorSubject<String>('App title');
  private title$ = this.title.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setTitle(title: String) {
    this.title.next(title);
  }

  getTitle(): Observable<String> {
    return this.title$;
  }
}
```

Then in a component (let's say the [AppComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-title?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)) which will hold (and show) the `title`, you subscribe to the `appService#getTitle()` method and update the `title` property accordingly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: String;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getTitle().subscribe(appTitle => this.title = appTitle);
  }
}
```

Now in every [component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-title?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts) you inject the `AppService` (when needed to update the title) and call the `appService#setTitle()`. For example, a `hello` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<p><b>Hello</b> component content</p>`,
  styles: []
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.setTitle('Hello Component');
  }
}
```

See this **[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-title)** (Tested with Angular 6)

Comment: thank you for perfect answer. One more thing is missing which is a registration of provider in app.module.ts `providers: [AppService]`

Comment: you are correct code was already there but you was just missed to mention in explanation only.

Comment: with angular 11 didn't work
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Angular [titleService](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title) to display the page title in the header component like below:

Header component .ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }
}
```

Header component .html:

```
<div class="title-bar">
    {{titleService.getTitle()}}
</div>
```

Then in any component you can set the page title using the Angular **titleService** and it will automatically change in the title and header sections:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle("Component's title");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a champ! Is it possible to differ my browser title from this title ?

Comment: You can based on the browser title display a certain title in the header. For example set the browser title to “Contact” and check in the header component using the title service if the browser title is “Contact” then display “Contact us” in the header title for example.

Comment: Also you can create an array of browser title as key and header title as value and display the corresponding header title of the current browser title without using if.

Comment: @AliRida an [alternative would be to use observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286357/angular-display-title-of-selected-component/51287553#51287553) in order to get notified only when the title changes.

Comment: That’s true @lealceldeiro, there are many solutions, it depends on the needs and the project structure.

Comment: How can I do this with components that I have both, nested in a dashboard like super-component as well as individually? If I set the title from the sub- and the dashboard component, it's likely overwritten by one of the sub-components of the dashboard.

Comment: *FYI* You also need to make sure title is imported at the top of your header component.ts as well as in any components where you plan to call this titleService:
`import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create a new component, call it `header`, and place it in your pages. This component will be responsible for displaying the title / any header you like
2. Use a service and update a `title` variable when someone enters a specific component

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [`ComponentFactoryResolver`](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)

```
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

onActivated(component) {
  this.activeSelector =    
  this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.constructor).selector;    
}
```

and on template,

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivated($event)"></router-outlet>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-usfxun?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Can I use anything then the selector? So add a name or something?

Comment: yeah its just a variable name

Comment: How exactly can I use a variable? this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.constructor).title doesn't work when I make variable title in my component. Sorry for the noob questions im new to Angular.

Comment: you cannot do that way it is just to get the name of the selector you use in the component, if you want to share a variable you shoumd implement a service as mentioned in the other answer